# create a variable showing the current and next date

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataset that is somehow similar to the following

```
df1 <-  data.frame(
                   id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                   x= seq.int(1,10,1),
                  date = seq.Date(from = as_date("2020-01-01"),to = as_date("2020-01-10"),by = "1 day"), 
                  new_date = c(NA,NA,"2020-01-03","2020-01-04",NA,NA,NA,"2020-01-08","2020-01-09",NA))

df1
```

I would like to create a new variable showing the date where the x is equal to 3 and 8 as well as a day after x is equal to 3 to 8 (similar to new_date var) Please note that in reality, I do not know what comes after 3 or 8 so to create the "new_date" variable based on that. I only know something happened on 2020-01-03 and 2020-01-08 and I would like to create a variable based on these special dates including these special dates and a day after them.

Thanks for your help.
S

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can get the index where `x` is 3, 8 and  copy the `date` values for those index and the index after that.

```
inds <- which(df$x %in% c(3, 8))
df$new_date <- as.Date(NA)
df$new_date[c(inds, inds + 1)] <- df$date[c(c(inds, inds + 1))]
df

#    x       date   new_date
#1   1 2020-01-01       <NA>
#2   2 2020-01-02       <NA>
#3   3 2020-01-03 2020-01-03
#4   4 2020-01-04 2020-01-04
#5   5 2020-01-05       <NA>
#6   6 2020-01-06       <NA>
#7   7 2020-01-07       <NA>
#8   8 2020-01-08 2020-01-08
#9   9 2020-01-09 2020-01-09
#10 10 2020-01-10       <NA>
```

In `dplyr` we can use `if_else` with `lag` to assign `new_date` values.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>%
           mutate(new_date = if_else(x %in% c(3, 8) | lag(x) %in% c(3, 8),
                                     date, as.Date(NA)))
df1
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak, I, however, have a question what if I wanted to rely on the values in the date variable only when I am passing ifelse condition not the values of x variable?

Comment: @SeyedHosseini You can do the same with dates as well. `inds <- df1$date %in% as.Date(c('2020-01-03', '2020-01-08'))`. The same change you need to do with `dplyr` answer as well. Change `c(3, 8)` to `as.Date(c('2020-01-03', '2020-01-08'))`